# Sass compiles background-position values to 100% in Laravel Mix ^4.0.7

Tags: css, sass, laravel-mix

How do I stop SASS from compiling the `background-property` to `100%`?

```
background-position: center right #{"calc(.4em + .1875rem)"};
```

What I tried is applying [string interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) on the values, just like I did on the calc function.

```
background-position: #{"center"} #{"right"} #{"calc(.4em + .1875rem)"};
```

I expected the non-calculated string, with just `center right calc(.4em + .1875rem)` as the value.

Comment: Your first snippet works fine for me. (It also works without any string interpolation at all.) Are you sure you’re looking at the right and current output? If so, which version of Sass?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Laravel Mix (4.1.2) to compile my SASS files*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared to be the `normalizePositions` option in the CssNano that is set to default in Laravel Mix.

To solve this issue, simply disabling the option did the trick:

```
mix.options({
    cssNano: {normalizePositions: false}
});
```